# Wordpress post filtering

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to filter my custom post type by published year.
I have something like this:

> Filter posts for 2015 / 2016.

The years are links which are redirecting with $_GET vars like `'?year=2015'` and `'?year=2016'`

In the custom page i have this:

```
$year = isset($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : '';

if ($year == '2015') {
    $the_query = new WP_Query('year=2015&post_type=events');
} else {
    $the_query = new WP_Query('post_type=events');
}
```

But if i click the 2015 year i'm redirecting to the index page. I tried make query like this `$the_query = new WP_Query('year=2015&post_type=events');` and it works, but cannot make it work with the GET or is there a better way to do that? (sorry for my English)

Also tried this:

```
$year = isset($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : '';

$the_query = new WP_Query('year='. (int)$year .'&post_type=events');
```

And here is the problem: My 2016 posts are filtering, but when i pass 2015 to the GET parameter, it redirects to the index page.

Comment: Any post in 2015 (database) ?

Comment: @ArshidKV Of course i have that posts.